# How to resue a jquery dialgue in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have jquery shown below for a jquery dialogue.Here div `idTestForm` is used as popup window.I want to reuse it for any number of Div's coming under any pages.If that is the case first step i will do is i will create separate .js file i will add this script.But i don't know how to change code in order to make it for any kind of Div's ie, how to pass div from any pages??etc

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function showBscDetails() {
                $("#idTestForm").dialog({
                    open: function () {
                        $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-error");
                    },
                    title: 'Leaf Details',
                    appendTo: "form",
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    show: 'blind',
                    hide: 'blind',
                    width: 1100,
                    height: 600
                }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "#6A7667");
                $("#idTestForm").on('dialogclose', function (event) {

                    location.reload(true);


                });
            }
```

**EDIT**
As of now i am calling this function from scriptmanager.registerstartupscript from code behind ie c# file

Comment: pass div id as a parameter of the method.

Comment: How i can use it,can u post a code snippet?

Comment: function showBscDetails(divObj) {
                $("#" + divObj).dialog({})

Comment: But form title and like informations how can i chage?

Comment: if you want to change the title, then you can also add another parameter in the method, like function showBscDetails(divObj, pageTitle). and you can call this from any page where this js is referenced by: showBscDetails("divRegister", "Registration")

Comment: i am calling this function from scriptmanager.registerstartupscript from c# file, does that work??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110029/discussion-between-peter-and-nab).

Comment: you can try, but the general idea is, pass all the changeable value from the calling function by parameter and make this Ui dialog function common.